# Change appearance of biblatex undefined references

Tags: biblatex

I am currently using `biblatex` to handle my bibliography. In comparison to BibTeX, undefined references are visualized as [bold citation key] instead of "[?]". Since my citation keys are rather long, this really messes up my document when I write some text and intend to fill in the citations later.

Is there any way to change the appearance of undefined references in `biblatex`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\begin{document}
\cite{authorlastname2017firstwordoftitle}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Update

`biblatex` uses the internal formatting macro `\abx@missing` defined as

```
\protected\def\abx@missing#1{%
  \mbox{\reset@font\bfseries#1}}
```

in case some object is missing. It applies to missing citations, but also to missing bibliography strings and fields.

If you redefine this macro you may also get a different output for other missing objects.

Newer versions of `biblatex` have the command

```
\def\abx@missing@entry#1{%
  \abx@missing{#1}}
```

specifically for missing entries/citations. You can redefine it with

```
\makeatletter
\def\abx@missing@entry#1{%
  \abx@missing{??}}
\makeatother
```

in your preamble to typeset bold question marks instead of the entry key.

See also [Wanted: question mark instead of bibtex key for missing citations (biblatex)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/433789/35864), [How to customize the style of citekey if the bib item does not exist](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/495364/35864).

---

### Old answer

This is controlled by the internal command `\abx@missing`. Its default is

```
\protected\def\abx@missing#1{%
  \mbox{\reset@font\bfseries#1}}
```

Add

```
\makeatletter
\protected\def\abx@missing#1{\textbf{?}}
\makeatother
```

to your preamble to just see a bold question mark if something is missing.