# How to customize the style of citekey if the bib item does not exist

Tags: biblatex

The is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{my.bib}

\begin{document}
test \autocite{not-exist-bib-citekey}
\end{document}
```

In the resulting pdf, you can see that "not-exist-bib-citekey" is in bold font.

I want to style it, for example, with red color, so as to make it more distinct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following [Wanted: question mark instead of bibtex key for missing citations (biblatex)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/433789/35864) the macro `\abx@missing@entry` was introduced. `\abx@missing@entry` is used to typeset missing entry keys, it defaults to `\abx@missing`, which is used for all kinds of missing things (mainly bibstrings).

So if you *only* want to influence missing entry keys, go with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\protected\def\abx@missing@entry#1{%
  \mbox{\reset@font\color{red}??#1??}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
test \autocite{missing-key}
\end{document}
```

[image: "test [??missing-key??]", the part in the square brackets is shown in bold red]

For most intents and purposes, this will give the same results as changing `\abx@missing` and one may even want to make missing bibstrings and other similar issues pop with red colour as well...

Answer (score 3):

BibLaTeX uses `\abx@missing` to print missing citation entries. You just need to redefine it:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\protected\def\abx@missing#1{%
  \mbox{\reset@font\color{red}#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
test \autocite{not-exist-bib-citekey}
\end{document}
```

> [image]